# Android ConstraintLayout Keyboard showing

Tags: android-constraintlayout

When I use ConstraintLayout as root view group, and when keyboard is being showing, my views in the root view don't up as with RelativeLayout and others layouts, not important which options I set in manifest.xml for android:windowSoftInputMode... Do you have same problem? It is possible to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Please post your layout code.